# translation of simple excel formula

Tags: resources

hi does anyone know of any websites that lists simple excel formula in chinese?

e.g. 
“=sum” --> 把所有选项加起来
“=CONCATENATE” --> 把所有选项融为一体

i'm trying to teach my china colleagues some simple excel formula to make them more efficient in their work.

thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft official website has those information.

https://support.office.com/zh-cn/excel

Click 常用函数 to show the list of popular Excel functions.